# how to use or create temp table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am pretty new to Oracle.

I am just stuck when i try to achieve the following logic. I am creating a sql script in oracle that will help me to generate a report. This script will run twice a day so i should't pick the same file when it runs next time.

1) run the query and save the result setand store the Order Id in the temp table when the job runs @11 Am
2) Run the query second time @ 3 pm check the temp table and return the result set that's not in temp table.

Following query will generate the result set but not sure how to create a temp table and valid against when it run.

```
    select 
        rownum as LineNum, 
        'New' as ActionCode,
        ORDER_ID,
       AmountType,
       trun(sysdate),
       trun(systime)
       from crd.V_IVZ_T19 t19
where 
    (t19.acct_cd in 
       (select fc.child_acct_cd 
            from cs_config fc
        where fc.parent_acct ike 'G_TRI_RPT'))

and t19.date>=  trunc(sysdate)
and t19.date<=  trunc(sysdate);
```

Any help much appreciated. I am not sure how to get only the timestamp also.

Comment: Your date check looks like you want to check a range but will simply check that t19.date is the current date.

Comment: You can create a normal table place of Temp table becuase temp table data will be deleted once the session is disconnected. In normal table you store your result and before the process of next day, truncate the table and load it again for the day

Comment: @BriteSponge, t19.date is the Orderdate in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TEMP table is not the idea here, cause temp table data will not store the data for a long time (just for a session), you just need to create a normal table. Hope it will help you:

```
--- table for storing ORDER_ID for further checking, make a correct DataType, you also can add date period in the table to control expired order_ids';

CREATE TABLE order_id_store (
       order_id NUMBER,
       end_date DATE
);


--- filling the table for further checking
INSERT INTO order_id_store 
       SELECT ORDER_ID, trunc(sysdate)
              FROM crd.V_IVZ_T19 t19
              WHERE t19.order_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT order_id FROM order_id_store)
              AND t19.date>=  trunc(sysdate)
              AND t19.date<=  trunc(sysdate);

--- delete no need data by date period, for example for last 2 days:
DELETE FROM order_id_store WHERE end_date <= trunc(SYSDATE - 2);
COMMIT;

---- for select report without already existed data
SELECT 
        rownum as LineNum, 
        'New' as ActionCode,
        ORDER_ID,
       AmountType,
       trun(sysdate),
       trun(systime)
FROM crd.V_IVZ_T19 t19
WHERE 
    (t19.acct_cd in 
       (select fc.child_acct_cd 
            from cs_config fc
        where fc.parent_acct ike 'G_TRI_RPT'))
     AND t19.order_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT order_id FROM order_id_store) 
     AND t19.date>=  trunc(sysdate)
     AND t19.date<=  trunc(sysdate);
```

I'm not sure about your "t19.date>=" and "t19.date<=", cause the close duration taking there, make that correct if it's not.